# Using VBA to enter data into website text/javascript field

Tags: javascript, vba, input

I'm trying to automate the running of a report. So far, I'm able to navigate to the report page and login, but I am stuck on how to enter data into the form to create the parameters of the report (other than by using SendKeys, which seems ineffective)

Here is my code so far:

```
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim MyBrowser As InternetExplorer

Sub Login2()

Dim MyHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
Dim MyURL As String

MyURL = "https://mc.s7.exacttarget.com/cloud/#app/Email/Content/Tracking/SubscriberReports/AsyncReportCreate.aspx?r=/ExactTarget/Tracking Reports/Recent Email Sending Summary&HistoryNodeID=REPORT_HISTORY"
MyUsername = "*************"
MyPassword = "*************"

Set MyBrowser = New InternetExplorer
MyBrowser.Silent = True
MyBrowser.Top = 0
MyBrowser.Left = 0
MyBrowser.AddressBar = 0
MyBrowser.StatusBar = 0
MyBrowser.Toolbar = 0
MyBrowser.Visible = True

MyBrowser.Navigate MyURL

Do
Loop Until MyBrowser.ReadyState = 4

Set HTMLDoc = MyBrowser.document
HTMLDoc.all.UserName.Value = MyUsername
HTMLDoc.all.Password.Value = MyPassword

For Each MyHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
If MyHTML_Element.Type = "submit" Then MyHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
Next

Do
Loop Until MyBrowser.ReadyState = 4

HTMLDoc.getElementsById("ReportParameterPicker1_rp_StartDate_picker").Value = "2014.01.01.0.0.0"


End Sub
```

I get the Run-time error '438: Object doesn't support this property of method.

Screenshot of the report form:
[url]https://gyazo.com/db1a5e7d74bc836e771b7915d33f5abd[/url]

Ideally, I'd like to scroll through the form, filling out input areas with data populated on my Excel sheet.

Another issue I faced when trying to do this, is the program trying to take actions before the webpage had loaded fully, even though I have the "ReadyState" part in there.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: What are the tagname and type of `ReportParameterPicker1_rp_StartDate_picker`? Could you include the corresponding fragment from the page source?

Comment: Sorry, there was supposed to be a screenshot: https://gyazo.com/4a74664e00b10f97f8e0c0009cfdcfc3

Comment: Also, I realize there's a typo, I added an "s" in "getElementsById".  I correct it, but still doesn't work.